# How to use in jQuery :not and hasClass() to get a specific element without a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I have this line of code:

```
$('#sitesAccordion .groupOfSites').click(function() {
    var lastOpenSite = $(this).siblings().hasClass(':not(.closedTab)');
    console.log(lastOpenSite);
});
```

I get "false" instead of getting one of the other elements (assuming that there is one - and there must be). I guess the problem is with:

```
.hasClass(':not(.closedTab)');
```

What is the problem?

My purpose is to create my own accordion (without using jQuery UI)

and I am trying to write it like this:

```
$('#sitesAccordion .groupOfSites').click(function() {

    //Get the last opened tab
    var lastOpenSite = $(this).siblings().hasClass(':not(.closedTab)');

    //Close last opened tab and add class
    lastOpenSite.hide().toggleClass('closedTab');

    //Open the current Tab
    $(this).children('.accordionContent').toggle('fast');

    // remove class from open tab
    $(this).toggleClass('closedTab');


});
```

Is this the best way?
thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use the [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not) function instead:

```
var lastOpenSite = $(this).siblings().not('.closedTab');
```

`hasClass` only tests whether an element has a class, `not` will remove elements from the selected set matching the provided selector.

Answer (score 115):

It's much easier to do like this:

```
if(!$('#foo').hasClass('bar')) { 
  ...
}
```

The ! in front of the criteria means false, works in most programming languages.

Comment: This won't work for what the OP is trying to do. It just tests whether `#foo` has a class or not, it doesn't reduce the matched set of elements to those that have it.

Comment: this way works pretty good in my totally different situation. thanks.

Comment: all i was doing wrong was putting ! with braces `!($(this).hasClass())` that didnt worked.

Answer (score 7):

jQuery's `hasClass()` method returns a boolean (true/false) and not an element. Also, the parameter to be given to it is a class name and not a selector as such.

For ex: `x.hasClass('error');`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [jQuery - is(selector) Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/traversal-is.htm):

```
var lastOpenSite = $(this).siblings().is(':not(.closedTab)');
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this was true at the time of the original posting, but the siblings method allows selectors, so a reduction of what the OP listed should work.

```
 $(this).siblings(':not(.closedTab)');
```