# how to use :not selector in symfony's css selector component

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

I want to simulate what I can achieve in jQuery by 
`$('.someClass:not(.hidden)')`

I tried below code.

`$crawler->filter('someClass:not(.hidden)')`

but it seems not working

Comment: You're missing a dot before `someClass`. Fix it and let us know if the issue still exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of Possible duphttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743026/how-to-use-in-jquery-not-

Comment: @RukmiPatel here OP is asking for symphony's css selector component, the link you provided is for jquery..

Comment: thanks @Jakub Matczak i was missing the dot

Comment: @HatemTito as per the docs from symphony website there are several pseudo elements which are not supported by css selector, though there is no any reference for `:not`.. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html

Comment: i checked the documentation first and thought that `:not` is not supported but i was not sure so i asked here but i was missing actually a dot  @NishantSolanki

Comment: @HatemTito no issues, glad you got your answer. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a dot before `someClass`.

Try with:

```
$crawler->filter('.someClass:not(.hidden)')
```

Comment: what about an entire element like

$crawler->filter(':not(h6)')