# correct jquery syntax on the each of the selector for checking class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check for a class if it not exists then do some work, else skip it over

```
    $.each($(":not textarea.hasClass('encypted')", "#"+formID),function(k){ 
   do the code part
});
```

what i am doing here is to check if the textarea does not have a class encypted and only then go inside and do its work, if it has that class, just skip the entire code part

Comment: That's not how the pseudo-class `:not()` works. And that's not how CSS selectors (or jQuery work)

Comment: Check [How to use in jQuery :not and hasClass() to get a specific element without a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743026/how-to-use-in-jquery-not-and-hasclass-to-get-a-specific-element-without-a-cla)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:not()` to directly select the textareas which *do not* have the given class:

```js
$(`#${formID} textarea:not(.encrypted)`).each(function() {
  // your code here...
});
```

Comment: but i also need to add the formID which is dynamic, just cannot add all the textarea

Comment: @Regual And what's the problem? The selector is a string. The `formID` is a string. There's string concatenation...

Comment: and where are you doing it @Andreas

Comment: @Regual I updated the answer to include the form selector.

Comment: why you included the { and }

Comment: It's a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). It's an ES6 feature which allows for more concise string concatenation

Comment: _"and where are you doing it"_ - Where it's needed to build a valid CSS selector that does select the elements I want o.O